# Is it undefined to initialize a class member in overloaded operator new?

Tags: c++, initialization, new-operator, undefined-behavior

Take a small example where, I am trying to find out if a variable is allocated on heap or not:

```
struct A
{
  bool isOnHeap;
  A () {}  // not touching isOnHeap
 ~A () {}

  void* operator new (size_t size)
  {
    A* p = (A*) malloc(size);
    p->isOnHeap = true;  // setting it to true
    return p;
  }
  void operator delete (void *p) { free(p); }
};
```

It gives [expected result in g++-4.5](http://www.ideone.com/evVUA) (with warning for stack object). Is it ill defined 
to do such operations ?

Comment: I don't think that kind of information is worth overloading `new` — that's a rather advanced feature, of limited use.

Comment: I'm not going to go standard diving, but I'm going to vote yes, it is undefined.  `*p` does not exist yet, and there are very very few things you can do with objects that don't exist yet... accessing their members is almost certainly not one of them.

Answer (score 6):

You can't initialize class members in an overloaded `operator new` because the object's lifetime hasn't started. You can only initialize members during the construction of the object.

You have no guarantee that the implementation won't wipe the memory between the time `operator new` returns and the time the object's construction starts or that during object construction members that are specified to have an indeterminate value by the standard (e.g. because they are POD and not explicitly initialized in the constructor like `isOnHeap`) aren't deliberately set to something by the implementation.

Note that `A` has a non-trivial constructor (it is user-declared), so its lifetime doesn't start when the storage for the object is allocated (ISO/IEC 14882:2003, 3.8 [basic.life] / 1) and the program has *undefined behavior* if it uses a pointer to the storage for the object to access a non-static data member (3.8 / 5). Even if `A` was a POD type, it's value after the completion of the *new-expression* would still be indeterminate rather than necessarily being related to the values in the bytes in the storage for the object before the *new-expression* was evaluated.

Comment: It is a question that was bothering me too. Technically, the lifetime of the boolean member has already started, since for `bool` object the lifetime begins as soon as the storage is allocated. However, the lifetime of the entire `A` has not started yet, since the constructor is not trivial. So, does the language spec say that in this case the value of the `bool` member will not generally be defined inside the `A`s constructor?

Comment: I would not say "the storage was allocated". Operator new is expected to provide memory only, and compiler may do something with the memory after thar. What about things like "value initialization" or "zero initialization"? What about A *a= new A vs A *a = new A()?

Comment: @Suma: I don't understand what you are getting at in your comment. Most `operator new` do just allocate storage, when I said "storage is allocated" that is what I was referring too. What the rest of a _new-expression_ does with the allocated storage depends on the exact _new-expression_ used and, to some extent, the details of the implementation.

Comment: I use value initialization as an example why I think the notion "the lifetime of the boolean member has already started" is wrong. But I guess my example is wrong, as value or zero initialization is applicable only when there is no user provided constructor. Still, I think the sentence "Technically, the lifetime of the boolean member has already started, since for bool object the lifetime begins as soon as the storage is allocated" is not correct, as I do not think you can assume inside of "new" that the lifetime of the members has already started, but I am unable to explain why.

Comment: ... note: I forgot to mark my original comment was not in response to your answer, but to the comment by AndreyT.

Comment: I think it's arguable whether the lifetime of the `bool` has started but I think that it will be (re-)initialized when the `A` object finally gets constructed. Whether that means it is given a specific value or just now indeterminate depends on the exact initialization used. A purely POD object doesn't ever have to be initialized, you can just write and read to its storage as soon as it's allocated but, as I understand it, if you do (re-)initialize it (e.g. with a placement new), then if the new value is indeterminate that doesn't mean the old value is preserved.

Answer (score 3):

Even when not considering the operator new itself (which is nonstandard and I would even say ugly, but knowing the exact details of some particular compiler it might be workable), there is another problem with this, which renders it useless anyway: You have no guarantee the value od isOnHeap will not be true when allocated on the stack. The stack is not initialized and any garbage from function invocations done before can be found there.

Answer (score 3):

As Charles said, the object only comes to lifetime after it has been newed, so setting data within your implementation of new is rather dangerous.

Also, when your developers use tools like Lint, there's a big chance that it complains that the member isOnHeap is not initialized in the constructor.  If then someone thinks "hey, Lint is right, let's initialize isOnHeap in the constructor of A", this will undermine the mechanism that you try to achieve.

There is a second case of which you probably didn't think.  Suppose that someone writes this:

```
class MyClass
   {
   public:
      ...
   private:
      struct A m_a;
   };

int main()
   {
   MyClass *myVariable = new MyClass();
   }
```

Then your implementation of new will not be called.  Nevertheless the instance of A is allocated on the heap (as part of the MyClass instance).

Can you explain why you want to know whether something has been allocated on the heap or not?  Maybe there's another, more elegant solution to your problem.